# How can i set custom pagination in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set a custom pagination for my API endpoint, where if there is a filter in the URL, Django must return a specific amount of records, and another amount of records  if there isn't any filter.

I have the following code:

```
valid_filters = {'Name', 'Date'}
def _has_valid_filters(iterable):
    return not valid_filters.isdisjoint(iterable)

class MyPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_page_size(self, request):
        if _has_valid_filters(request.query_params.items()):
            return 15
        else:
            return 30

class MyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = MyPagination
    http_method_names = ['get']
    serializer_class = My_Serializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        valid_filters = {
            'Name': 'Name',
            'Date': 'Date__gte',
        }

        filters = {valid_filters[key]: value for key, value in self.request.query_params.items() if key in valid_filters.keys()}

        queryset = Model.objects.filter(**filters)

        return queryset
```

The problem with this code is that the pagination is always the same. While `MyPagination` is called, it looks like `get_page_size` is never called for some reason. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: That's correct. The parent class you've chosen doesn't use page size, but limit and `get_limit()`.

Comment: I think get_limit is what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `LimitOffsetPagination` has a method named `get_page_size` so it would never be called. I believe what you want is `get_limit()`.

That said, I think this is a bit to unRESTful to obscure page limit in this way and I believe this should just be controlled by the query parameters fed by the client.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I'm trying to limit the number of records received because without it, the query becomes too slow to execute. I'm taking a look into get_limit